# Wann verselbstständigte sich das Tanzen auf vielen Hochzeiten?

Tags: phrase, etymology

Über Leute wie ich, die sich in vielen unterschiedlichen Gemeinschaften auf verschiedenste Arten einbringen, sagt man:

> Der tanzt auf zu vielen Hochzeiten.

Das ergibt natürlich an sich ein sehr schönes und plausibles Bild. Daher würde mich interessieren:

- Was sind die ältesten, nachweisbaren Quellen für diese Phrase?
- Welche der möglichen Etymologien (ich liste sie nicht auf, ich möchte niemanden beeinflussen) lässt sich bestätigen/widerlegen; wo kommt der Ausdruck also her?
- War die Phrase gegebenenfalls früher auf nur ein Geschlecht begrenzt?

Comment: Original heißt die Redewendung *Man kann nicht auf zwei Hochzeiten tanzen*. Eine Google-Recherche hat allerdings keine etymologischen Ursprünge zutage gebracht. Ich habe nur synonyme Redewendungen und Alternativen gefunden.

Comment: Ich kenne auch eine derbere Variante, wonach man mit  "mit einem Arsch nicht auf zwei Kirtagen tanzen" kann. Wann und wo diese Redewendung aufkam wird sich, wie bei den meisten Sprichwörtern, wohl nicht mehr feststellen lassen; insgesamt ergibt sich aber ein stimmiges Bild, wie ich finde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mit Google Books habe ich die folgenden Ergebnisse gefunden:

Deutsche Vierteljahrsschrift, 1841, Verlag J. G. Cotta.

> Eine lebhafte Kontroverse war vorausgegangen; namentlich war geltend gemacht worden, **Niemand könne auf zwei Hochzeiten zugleich seyn**, also könne der Mitverlag eines Deutschen ein französisches Werk in Deutschland nicht schützen

Auch mit alternativen Schreibweisen wie  *zwey* oder *Hochzeyten* habe ich nichts Älteres gefunden.

Außerdem gibt es noch Resultate aus Büchern, die Ausdrücke „aus dem Volk“ sammeln, demnach wird dieser Ausdruck schon einige Zeit in Verwendung gewesen sein:

1861    *So spricht das Volk: volksthümliche Redensarten und Sprichwörter* von Franz Sandvoss:

> mit einem arsch auf zwei hochzeiten sein wollen

Answer (score 1):

This one may be ours. I don't have an earlier attestation that 1908, but in that year it made a list of [traditional proverbs](http://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/iiddica/Khronologye/y_19yh/Bernshteyn/ber_grob.html), so it must go back a ways from there.

If you go to the link, it's no. 177 on the list (transcribed from the Yiddish using the official phonetic Romanization):

mit eyn tokhes kon men nit tantsn af tsvey khasenes.

Comment: I think there aren't but I handful non-Jewish people that understand what you meant be "ours" :)